# Ruby on Rails: No routes match for[POST] '/contacts/new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

Rails 5. keep getting the error that route could not be found. What did I do wrong here?

App/views/contacts/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for "@contact" do |f| %>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :email %>
                    <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control'  %>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= f.label :comments %>
                    <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
                </div> 

                <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>

     <% end %>
```

routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: 'pages#home'
get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
resources :contacts
end
```

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
        redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
    else
        redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured."
    end
end

private
    def contact_params
        params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
```

end

contact.rb (model file, blank for now)

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am curious why its making a post request. What are you doing that fires the post request? Does this happen when you submit the form?

Comment: Yes. It's a form that's submitting, and usually when submitting it's automatically a POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotes around your @contact variable in your form, try just using the plain @contact variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. Can't believe I wasted hours trying to figure out why it didn't work. I'm an idiot lol